# creating a time-series graph

Tags: r

I am doing some postgraduate research and am working with very large 12 year data-sets. Below are a couple of lines of the raw data:

```
41705   3/01/2001 0:00:00   00:53:26.489    -38.7846    176.7535    508.4   30.2    2   1   28.7    1.3 66  22.1    0.1 2748.1
27508   3/01/2001 0:00:00   02:25:41.829    -40.8469    175.4642    491.6   30.2    2   1   7.4 0.4 105 18.5    2.2 2657.4
36381   3/01/2001 0:00:00   02:38:14.660    -41.0886    172.2131    393.8   30  2   1   38.6    0.8 35  48.2    1.3 2128.4
100759  13/01/2001 0:00:00  02:41:14.834   -41.2795     172.284     388.4   22.6    3   3   1.5 0.2 128 7.5 0.4 2099.4
```

but need to be converted into 1 hour time intervals for every hour of every day of the year (i.e. the only data I am interested in are in columns 3 (date - in DD/MM/YYYY 0:00:00 format) and 4 (time - HH:MM:SS.mmm format)) and the polarity of column 5 (ie negative and positive). Up until now I have been wrestling with it in Excel but I have gone beyond its capabilities and have just (today) downloaded R to learn.
From this data I need to create a time series graph with hours on the x-axis and days of the year on the y-axis summarising the 12-year data-set. [here is an example of the graph I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEqUQ.jpg). However, as I'm a complete novice when it comes to R, I have no idea where to begin!

Any pointers would be really appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You could start by saying what it is that you expect to see. At the moment the vague request for something by hour has no specificity. You should also do some searching since aggregating by hour or other time interval is a frequent question here. (Counts? Means? <what>?) The duplicate-police are ever-present.

Comment: @BondedDust In fairness, OP did post a link to an example of what they want.

Comment: Can you explain the time format? What does `09:03.1` mean in H:M:S??

Comment: [This article](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/heatmaps_in_r.html) may help you get in your way; it is an introduction on how to create heat maps. If you are a novice with R, I recommend you check the [Quick-R tutorial](http://statmethods.net) as a good starting point.

Comment: The time in column 4 cannot be H:M.S (30, 57, 35 in rows 2-4 cannot be hours).

Comment: @jhoward My guess is that the questioner doesn't know how that plot was made and he is really asking us to "recommend a tool." I have guesses about how one might develop such a plot but that would need to actual dataset to serve as a testing ground.

Comment: @jhoward - sorry, the format changed on me when it went into the post, I have edited it to make sense - column 3 (date - in DD/MM/YYYY 0:00:00 format where the 0:00:00 is nonsense) and column 4 (time - HH:MM:SS.mmm format). thanks

Comment: @BondedDust - Apologies for my poorly written post that didn't make it clear that I can and am doing the 1 hour time interval conversion in Excel (though I'm sure R can do it much more efficiently I'm not very new software confident). My real question is how to produce the graph as it can't be done in Excel and so I've literally today downloaded and installed R for that initial purpose.

Comment: @Barranka - thanks for the link to the article. I'll work my way through that (along with the general R familiarisation that I'm doing). Hopefully it'll be the answer :)

Comment: @xealeel I do not think that a heatmap is the right way to produce that graph. Heatmaps are for discretized data and you appears to be continuous by continuous, with the emphasis on appears, since there's not much that can be done with 4 cases.